# TOMCAT : SPNEGO CONFIGURATION ERROR

Tags: java, security, tomcat7, kerberos, spnego

I have troubles with SPNEGO TOMCAT 7 configuration: I follow this guide for setup:

[spnego-tomcat-config](https://dzone.com/articles/do-not-publish-configuring-tomcat-single-sign-on-w)

Here is my krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm=lctr.corp
default_keytab_name="C:/tomcat/conf/tomcat.keytab"
default_tkt_enctypes=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
default_tgs_enctypes=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
forwardable=true
[realms]
LCTR.CORP={
 kdc=AQPINF02.lctr.corp:88
}
[domain_realm]
lctr.corp=LCTR.CORP
.lctr.corp=LCTR.CORP
```

My jaas.conf

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
  required
  doNotPrompt=true
  principal="HTTP/TTS04.lctr.corp@LCTR.CORP"
  keyTab="C:/tomcat/conf/tomcat.keytab"
  storeKey=true
  useKeyTab=true
  useTicketCache=true
  isInitiator=true
  refreshKrb5Config=true
  moduleBanner=true
  storePass=true
  debug=true
  moduleBanner=true;
};
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
  required
  doNotPrompt=true
  principal="HTTP/TTS04.lctr.corp@LCTR.CORP"
  keyTab="C:/tomcat/conf/tomcat.keytab"
  storeKey=true
  useKeyTab=true
  useTicketCache=true
  isInitiator=true
  refreshKrb5Config=true
  moduleBanner=true
  storePass=true
  debug=true
  debug=true
  moduleBanner=true;
};
```

Now in Tomcat :

- web.xml

  ```
  <login-config>
      <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
  </login-config>

  <security-role>
    <description>Users</description>
    <role-name>Users</role-name>
  </security-role>    

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>User Area</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>Users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  ```
- server.xml

  ```
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
              connectionURL="ldap://AQPINF02.lctr.corp:3268" 
              userSubtree="true"
              userBase="DC=lctr,DC=corp" 
              userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
              userRoleName="memberOf" 
              roleBase="DC=lctr,DC=corp" 
              roleName="cn"
              roleSearch="(member={0})" 
              roleSubtree="true" 
              roleNested="true"/>
          <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps">
              <Context docBase="ROOT.war" path="">
                  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator"
                      storeDelegatedCredential="true" />
              </Context>
          </Host>
  </Engine>
  ```

I set up SPN in AD server, first my user was "devl-ast" and after configuration becomes "HTTP/TTS04.lctr.corp" ( I use this username to login when I start tomcat 7)

When I start tomcat and try to access "tts04.lctr.corp:8095" appear window to login (I put as I said HTTP/TTS04.lctr.corp and password), but appear an exception here is the log

```
SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
        javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090748, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580 ]; remaining name 'DC=lctr,DC=corp'
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
            at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUserBySearch(JNDIRealm.java:1709)
            at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1545)
            at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1473)
            at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getPrincipal(JNDIRealm.java:2379)
            at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getPrincipal(JNDIRealm.java:2295)
            at org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.authenticate(RealmBase.java:581)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator$AuthenticateAction.run(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:352)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator$AuthenticateAction.run(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:337)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:251)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:577)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

        ene 20, 2017 10:02:45 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
        FINE:  Failed authenticate() test
```

What I am doing wrong in my configuration, please help me.